# i can send value from my activity to broadcastreceiver but i can't use it for long time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

actually in my app i want to send a message when my phone making any phone calls...here the app installing time asking for parent number and its number sending to the broadcast receiver activity from my first activity...its received there and also toasting the value..but when i making phone call it value change to null...can anybody help me for access that value at phone calling time ..is it possible ??how..thank you my code is given below...

in my first activity sending value to broadcast receiver:

```
try
{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "try", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     Intent in = new Intent("my.action.string");
     in.putExtra("parent", PARENT);//this string sending to broadcast receiver
     sendBroadcast(in);
}
 catch (Exception e) 
 {
    // TODO: handle exception
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and my broadcast receiver is:

```
public class myBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    String out_number;
    String myparent;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myparent = intent.getExtras().getString("parent"); //this sting access the number first and then change to null at making phone call
        final String my=myparent;
        Toast.makeText(context, "broadcst"+myparent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
        {
            out_number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(context, "broadcst"+my+" "+out_number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SmsManager sm=SmsManager.getDefault();
            sm.sendTextMessage(myparent, "5554", "calling..to"+myparent, null, null); //5554 is my emulator number to check its in emulator
             Toast.makeText(context, "send"+out_number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * The Receiver is intended for the incoming calls read though the phone
 * state for more details see android.content.BroadcastReceiver
 * 
 * @author parul
 * 
 */

public class InComingCallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

  public static String LOG = "InComingCall";

  /*
   * (The onReceive is invoked when we receive an arbitrary intent from the
   * Incoming call Service)
   * 
   * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
   * android.content.Intent)
   */

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.v(LOG, "InComingCallReciever");

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle == null) {
      return;
    }
    String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    Log.v(LOG, "" + state);

    if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
      String phoneNumber = bundle
          .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

      Toast.makeText(context, "The Incoming Number is ..." + phoneNumber,
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Log.v(LOG, "incomming number is ... " + phoneNumber);
    } else {
      Log.v(LOG, "test 2 ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer..but actually i am getting a number in my another activity that number i want to access inside the broadcast receiver at making phone call...how its possible

Comment: wow..i solve my problem i can send the values through database and i can access any time in broadcast receiver.....thank u for all